# supervisor setup for .NET core web api Ubuntu server

Tags: .net, ubuntu, web, server, supervisord

I'm building .net core web api on ubuntu server. So i put my solution to `/home/maks/SA`, configured nginx and after commands dotnet restore, dotnet run everything works fine (i tested my solution using Postman). Now i need to setup supervisor to keep my app running. But all my tries failed:(  [supervisor log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5e1Bp.png)
[application log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpnAQ.png)

Conf file

```
[program:SA]
command=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/SA/SA.dll
directory=/var/SA/
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/SA.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/SA.out.log
```

I really need your help!

Comment: Also i tried 
    `[program:SA]
    command=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/SA/SA.dll --server.urls:http://*:5123
    directory=/var/SA/
    autostart=true
    autorestart=true
    stderr_logfile=/var/log/sa.err.log
    stdout_logfile=/var/log/sa.out.log
    environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
    stopsignal=INT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by using this instruction https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/linuxproduction and publishing by this command `dotnet publish -c release -r ubuntu.14.04-x64`